# Why did the ping process of port of the Apache IoTDB Version 1.3 local server fails?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know why the ping process fails for Apache IoTDB Version 1.3 port on the local server? The full command I write to connect to IoTDB is like this `Users Administrator>telnet 192.168.0.117:6667`. Is there an error for this command or what else do I need to do to be able to connect to IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

When you write this command for the local server of Apache IoTDB, There should be spaces between `telnet`, `ip`, and `port`, so you cannot use colons between `ip`, and `port`. Change that and try again.